# Write click event dynamically on jquery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, laravel

Here is the original html

```
<div class='cl_{{ $gen }}'>{{$gen->name}}</div>
<div class='jl_{{ $var }}'>{{$gen->name}}</div>
```

After looping over here is the html i got as output

I wanted to do if i click on the class cl_x, then the jl_x should be visible and other should be hidden and by default the first cl_1 should be visible. How can i do this ?

```
<div class='cl_1'>One</div>
<div class='cl_5'>Two</div>
<div class='cl_6'>Three</div>
<br>
<div class='jl_1'>Alpha</div>
<div class='jl_1'>Andrew</div>
<div class='jl_1'>Christ</div>
<div class='jl_5'>Anto</div>
<div class='jl_5'>Brito</div>
<div class='jl_6'>Oyster</div>
<div class='jl_6'>Beta</div>
```

**Note :** All the 1,5,6 are not standard as they are coming from database.

I really can't able to think how to achieve this. Help pls

But Here is what i have tried the logic

1. Inside Document Ready
2. Loop over the jquery like html
3. Write click event to show hide if they cick on cl_*
4. Trigger the click event for first occurance.

Don't worry about the html generated but the need is to write the jquery events dynamically or something else

But can't able to implement the code pls help

Script :

```
$(document).ready(function() {
//not sure whether i should loop over the jquery itself or write anything like the element starts with cl-* like that
});
```

**Update :**

Here is the [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/aaaf6us4/) i have so far

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Would move the unique identifiers to a different attribute and add a common class to all the `J` group

```
<div class='cl' data-gen="{{ $gen }}">{{$gen->name}}</div>
<div class='jl jl_{{ $var }}'>{{$gen->name}}</div>
```

JS

```
$(document).on('click','.cl',function(){
   $('.jl').hide().filter('.jl_' + $(this).data('gen') ).show();
})
```

Comment: Thanks, by default all class of `jl` should be hidden  ?

Comment: yeah..generally better to that with css ... don't have to wait for script to be ready

Comment: Thanks i have created the fiddle, may i know how to trigger the first cl_* by default ? https://jsfiddle.net/aaaf6us4/7/

Comment: can use css `:first-of-type` selector to show first of each. Easy to search that in google to see how it works

Comment: Thanks, i will do it :)

Comment: Hi, can you pls help on the first-of-type, Because i can't still find it how it works..

Answer (score 3):

You don't really want to use class for this - a custom data attribute makes sense, though. Like `<div class="cl" data-number="{{ $gen }}">` with `<div class="jl" data-number="{{$var}}">` on the other elements.

Then inside the `$(document).ready(...)` you can do something like:

```
$('.jl').hide().first().show();
$('.cl').click(function(){
    $('.jl').hide().filter('[data-number="' + $(this).data('number') + '"]').show();
})
```

It would also be good to make up more meaningful names than "cl" and "jl" - classes should generally be semantic.

Answer (score 1):

Add a base "jl" class to all your html that has anything with a "jl_*" so that you will have access to anything overall that has the "jl" class then toggle it hidden or not hidden like so:

HTML:

```
<div class='cl {{ $gen }}'>{{$gen->name}}</div>
<div class='jl {{ $var }}'>{{$gen->name}}</div>
```

JS:

```
$(document).on('click', '.cl', function(e){
  var classes = ($(e.target).attr("class").split(' '));
  $('.jl').toggleClass("hide");
  $('.jl' + "."+ classes[1]).toggleClass("hide");
});
```

Style:

```
.hide{
 display: none;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/rc368gjp/